# How to perform centralized error handling for pipelined method call in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to perform json parsing and save the result to a Hash Set. I want to use iter(), like:

```
let my_json_list = vec!("{\"name\":\"Tim\", \"age\":18}", "{\"name\":\"Alex\", \"age\":25}")
let mut my_hash_set::HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();
my_hash_set.extend(
            my_json_list.iter()
                        .map(|str| serde_json::from_str(str)) // return Result
                        .map(|json| json.pointer("/name") // return Option
                        .when_err_or_none(|err| skip();) // handle Err and None, not extend the map
                        .map(|key| key.as_str().unwrap().to_owned())
)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```rust
let my_json_list = vec![
    "{\"name\":\"Tim\", \"age\":18}",
    "{\"name\":\"Alex\", \"age\":25}",
];
let mut my_hash_set: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();
my_hash_set.extend(
    my_json_list
        .iter()
        .map(|str| serde_json::from_str::<Value>(str))
        .filter(|result| result.is_ok())
        .map(|result| result.unwrap())
        .filter(|json| json["name"].is_string())
        .map(|json| json["name"].as_str().unwrap().to_string()),
);
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: a judicious application of `filter_map` would make the code simpler and likely more efficient (by avoiding redundant operations): `let my_hash_set = my_json_list.iter().filter_map(|s| serde_json::from_str::<Value>(s).ok()).filter_map(|json| json["name"].as_str().map(String::from)).collect::<HashSet<_>>();`.

Comment: @Masklinn You are right. I did not know that method

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case I would define a dedicated `struct Person`, and let `serde` do the heavy lifting:

```
use serde_json; // 1.0.48
use serde; // 1.0.104

use serde::Deserialize;
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let my_json_list = vec!(
        "{\"name\":\"Tim\", \"age\":18}",
        "{\"name\":\"Alex\", \"age\":25}"
    );
    let my_hash_set : HashSet<String> = my_json_list
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|str| serde_json::from_str::<Person>(str)
            .ok() // convert Result -> Option
            .map(|person| person.name) // only interested in name
        )
        .collect(); // collect names into HashSet
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=607cfe125b5690fb89b23ca904da31cc

If you prefer a more ad-hoc solution without a struct:
use serde_json; // 1.0.48

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let my_json_list = vec!(
        "{\"name\":\"Tim\", \"age\":18}",
        "{\"name\":\"Alex\", \"age\":25}"
    );
    let my_hash_set : HashSet<String> = my_json_list
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|str| serde_json::from_str::<serde_json::Value>(str)
            .ok() // convert Result -> Option
            .and_then(|json_val| json_val.get("name")
                .and_then(|name_val| name_val.as_str()) // try to convert to &str
                .map(|str| str.to_string()) // convert &str to String
            )
        )
        .collect(); // collect names into HashSet
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=607cfe125b5690fb89b23ca904da31cc